# "Standard compliance" vs. "standards compliance"

Tags: grammatical-number

Searching the Internet I have found that both wordings "Social standard compliance" and "social standard**s** compliance" (standard vs. standardS) are used frequently.

I suppose that the wording "standard**s**" is correct, since it refers to a list of standards and not only one. But then, I've been told to use the singular "standard".

Which one is correct or are they both correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine, but have slightly different meanings.

When you use the singular:

> Social standard compliance

You are referring to compliance with the ethos of the standards, and general compliance with any standards whatever they may be.

When you use the plural

> Social standards compliance

The emphasis is placed on the individual standards, and not the abstract idea of a social standard.

There may be many social standards, and by using the plural, standards, you are articulating that you are compliant with every single standard.

The singular version has more of an air of generality about it, and an emphasis on the spirit of the social standard you are complying with.

Comment: Many many thanks for your answer; I kind of had an intuition of what you explained very clearly, but wasn't able to formulate it concretely. Being new here I cannot give any points to your answer but I marked it as "accepted" -- tanks again.

Comment: @Will My pleasure, pleased the answer was useful.